# Using python pandas timestamps in sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, scikit-learn

One of my dataframe columns is dates. In order to use it in my analysis I convert it to datetime as follows:

```
datetime_columns = ['my_dates']
for c in datetime_columns:
    df[c] = pd.to_datetime(df[c], infer_datetime_format=False)
```

Conversion does the job:

```
print df['my_dates'].dtype
datetime64[ns]
```

However, when I use it further, `sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score()` throws `TypeError` exception:

```
features = df[list(feature_columns)] # Includes 'my_dates'
labels = df[list(target_columns)]
cross_val_score(LinearRegression(), features.values, labels.values, cv=5)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

All my other columns (without my_dates) have numeric format:

```
print list((set(features.dtypes).union(set(labels.dtypes))))
[dtype('int8'), dtype('int64'), dtype('float64')]
```

This error occures only if 'my_dates' column is included in features. `cross_val_score()` seems not to work with timestamps, but I need it in my analysis. What is the pythonic or pandastic way to make it work?

Comment: why can't you use your `datetime` column as string when calling `cross_val_score()`?

Comment: @MaxU string returns the same `TypeError`

Comment: can you post the output of the following: `print(features.dtypes); print(labels.dtypes)`

Comment: so you do have `float` columns and `cross_val_score()` doesn't seem to like `float`s. You can identify them like this: `df.select_dtypes(include=['floating']).columns`

Comment: @MaxU it works OK with floats. If I remove datetime column from dataframe, it goes well. This error occures only if 'my_dates' column is included in features.

Comment: The only workaround i can think of is to convert your `my_dates` into a number (for example UNIX timestamp - # of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00`) or to a string

Comment: @MaxU So you can post an answer, can't you?

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your `my_dates` column into `np.int64` dtype in order to make `cross_val_score()` happy

Demo:

```
In [330]: df = pd.DataFrame({'my_dates':pd.date_range('2001-01-01', periods=10, freq='55555T')})

In [331]: df
Out[331]:
             my_dates
0 2001-01-01 00:00:00
1 2001-02-08 13:55:00
2 2001-03-19 03:50:00
3 2001-04-26 17:45:00
4 2001-06-04 07:40:00
5 2001-07-12 21:35:00
6 2001-08-20 11:30:00
7 2001-09-28 01:25:00
8 2001-11-05 15:20:00
9 2001-12-14 05:15:00


In [333]: df.my_dates.astype(np.int64) // 10**9
Out[333]:
0     978307200
1     981640500
2     984973800
3     988307100
4     991640400
5     994973700
6     998307000
7    1001640300
8    1004973600
9    1008306900
Name: my_dates, dtype: int64
```